# Pausing access to database, not instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to pause all access to an SQL Server 2008R2 database. I would not like to pause the service in services, because databases on that instance will be stopped as well.

Secondly,  If I set the database to single user, only the windows account can log in and I would actually like a different account to be logged in when paused.

Is there a way I can specify which account I want to log in when in single user? or is there a better way to accomplish this. Without having to write code to lock all accounts except a specific one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can lock access period at the role level
But you could put the users in a role (e. g. lockableUsers) and deny access at the database level to the role
[CREATE SERVER ROLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677610.aspx)

Or you could block at the port (1433)

Comment: if i block the port 1433, the user that is in will stay and no one else will be able to coonnect?

Comment: No you have have to block other users at the port level.  I forget the name of the Microsoft tool but you can do very granular blocking.